# I had an issue with SDL_Delay() in MacOS 10.14.6

Tags: c++, macos, sdl

It seems that the SDL_Delay() has some problem in macOS, instead of that we can use:

```
bool is_running = true;
SDL_Event event;
while (is_running) {
    while (SDL_PollEvent(&event)) {
        if (event.type == SDL_QUIT) {
            is_running = false;
        }
    }
    SDL_Delay(16);
}
```

But what should I use when I want my program to stop for 2 seconds.

Comment: Use a *timer*, and when active only handle relevant events (like the timer-elapsed and `SDL_QUIT` events).

Answer (score 0):

I found the answer:
https://discourse.libsdl.org/t/sdl2-cant-see-the-window/25835

> Ok, I found the issue. The window wouldn’t show up on OS X unless I had an event loop going (prior I had an SDL_Delay call).